# Use LsqFit for multi-variate output?

Tags: julia, least-squares

I wanted to fit a geometric mapping parameter with some input/output (x,y) points. The model is very simple:

```
xp = x .+ k.*x.*(x.^2+y.^2)
yp = y .+ k.*y.*(x.^2+y.^2)
```

k is the only parameter, (x,y) is an input point and (xp,yp) is an output point.
I formulated the input/output data array as:

```
x = [x for x=-2.:2. for y=-2.:2.]
y = [y for x=-2.:2. for y=-2.:2.]
in_data = [x y]
out_data = [xp yp]
```

However I'm confused about how to turn this into the LsqFit model, I tried:

```
k0=[0.]
@. model(x,p) = [x[:,1]+p[1]*x[:,1]*(x[:,1]^2+x[:,2]^2) x[:,2]+p[1]*x[:,2]*(x[:,1]^2+x[:,2]^2)]
ret = curve_fit(model, in_data, out_data, k0)
```

but got an error:

> DimensionMismatch("dimensions must match: a has dims (Base.OneTo(25),
> Base.OneTo(2)), must have singleton at dim 2")

So the question is: is it possible to use LsqFit for multi-variate output? (even though this particular problem can be solved analytically)

Comment: It seems to me that the minimization isn't well defined in your case? In terms of model fit, how would you compare a model for which the predicted (x, y) is off of your input data by (0.5, 0.5) compared to one that is off by (0.25, 0.75)? You should probably think about the appropriate norm to compute a scalar distance notion.

Comment: Isn't it just the 2 norm/Euclidean distance between input/output data points?

Answer (score 1):

OK Just figured out the correct way to do this. The vector output variable needs to be stacked together to form a 1D array. So the only changes needed is:

```
out_data = [xp; yp]
```

Comment: I think you also need to form a 1D column vector with the `in_data` as well, i.e., `in_data = [x; y]` Additionally, the `model()` function needs to reflect that change too.